# How to pass multiple list values as function parameters?

Tags: python, list, loops, python-requests, function-invocation

Would someone be able to help me understanding how can I pass values from multiple lists as function parameters? I'm trying to update email for each of myemailId with url that includes customerId.

my code so far:

```
emailId = [732853380,7331635674]
customerId = ['cust-12345-mer','cust-6789-mer']

for x, y in zip(emailId, customerId):
    def update_email(emailId, token, user, notes="https://myurl.com/customer?customerId =" + customerId):
        headers = {     'accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'token': token,
                    'user': user}
        endpoint = 'email/'
        body = {'emailId': emailId, 'user': user, 'notes': notes}
        requests.put(url = host + endpoint, headers = headers, json=body)
        return True
```

but receiving this error that is corresponding to the line that starts with `def update_email`...:

```
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you defining a function in a loop? Where are you calling the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't define the function for each loop iteration but once before executing the loop.

In order to pass the values, use:

```
emailId = [732853380, 7331635674]
customerId = ['cust-12345-mer', 'cust-6789-mer']


def update_email(emailId, token, user, customerId):
    notes = "https://myurl.com/customer?customerId =" + customerId
    headers = {'accept': 'application/json',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'token': token,
               'user': user}
    endpoint = 'email/'
    body = {'emailId': emailId, 'user': user, 'notes': notes}
    requests.put(url=host + endpoint, headers=headers, json=body)
    return True


for x, y in zip(emailId, customerId):
    update_email(x, token, user, y)
```

Answer (score 2):

`customerId` is the list, `y` is the value from that list. Use

```
notes="https://myurl.com/customer?customerId =" + y
```

Comment: @Gabip right, and I've asked them what on Earth they're doing. But I also think it's useful to understand what caused the error.

Comment: Agree, I saw your comment afterwards, that's why I removed my comment...